# Activity has leaked window DecorView

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So...i've been trying to add a documet to cloud firestore...and for the past 3 hours i've been looking at why does my progressdialog always leak window if i did everything the same as i did in other activities. i have a button to add an object to the database, and uppon clicking and quick validation, i proceed to load the dialog (and i've tryed hiding it multiple times over the code but still get this error)

```
    String stevilka_kartice = etStevilkaKartice.getText().toString().trim();
    String ime_trgovine = etImeTrgovine.getText().toString().trim();

    if(stevilka_kartice.isEmpty()) {
        etStevilkaKartice.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.stevilkaKarticeRequired));
        etStevilkaKartice.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(ime_trgovine.isEmpty()) {
        etImeTrgovine.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.imeTrgovineRequired));
        etImeTrgovine.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


    progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.addingCard));
    progressDialog.show();

    Kartica k = new Kartica(user.getUid(), ime_trgovine, stevilka_kartice);
    k.setUrl_slike("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/shoppingplus-5a575.appspot.com/o/kartice%2Fdefault_card.png?alt=media&token=5ea99819-8be6-4c61-845b-05879c1646c9");

    CollectionReference kartice = db.collection("kartice");
    kartice.add(k).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
            progressDialog.hide();
            Toast.makeText(DopolnitevKarticeActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.cardAdded), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            progressDialog.hide();
            Toast.makeText(DopolnitevKarticeActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.cardNotAdded), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    etStevilkaKartice.setText("");
    etImeTrgovine.setText("");

    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(DopolnitevKarticeActivity.this, KarticeActivity.class));
```

i put the hide method on the dialog past everything (right before i finish this and proceed to karticeactivity), dismissing, hiding in success and failed callbacks. For some reason it works when i only show it but not hide it (but that defeats the purpose if its not dismissed). as soon as i put the code to hide it it crashes

Comment: Because you're finishing the Activity before your `OnSuccessListener` is called. You need to execute everything you have after adding those listeners inside the listeners themselves.

Comment: Pelase add the entire error that you get and please responde with @AlexMamo